# How to run script with a function? (repeatedly)

Tags: python, database, function, tkinter, password-generator

I have a Python program where **a function imports another script and runs it**. But the script gets run **only the first time** the function is called.

`def Open_Generator(event):
    import PasswordGenerator`

Any tips?

*The function is called using a button in a tkinter window

Comment: If it really is intended to run as a script, use the `subprocess` module to run it like any other external command. Don't try to mix its state with your own process's state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is by design. You should only import a module once. Trying to import a module more than once will cause Python to re-fetch the module object from the cache, but this won't cause the module's code to execute a second time.

Most well-designed modules won't do anything right away when you import them, or at least won't do anything obviously visible. Generally, if you want a module to do work, you need to call one of its functions.

I'm guessing your `PasswordGenerator` module has some code at the file-level scope. In other words, it has code that isn't inside a function. Try to move that code into a function. Then you can call that function from `Open_Generator`.

```
import PasswordGenerator

def Open_Generator(event):
    my_password = PasswordGenerator.generate_password()
```